# Iterate over Array Columns in SQL For Loop

Tags: python, sql, loops, pyodbc

I'm trying to use a for loop to iterate over a file that contains my WHERE clause inputs.  I think there is some sort of format change I need to specify, because I'm getting an error after the last row of the first column.  (the same inputs are used for 2 different SQL Table Columns)

I've tried running my inputs as a list, array and file, but nothing seems to be doing the trick.  Any thoughts on how I can fix this in Python? I can tell I'm so close to finally getting it to work!

```
import numpy as np
import pyodbc
con = pyodbc.connect('DSN=*;UID=*;PWD=*')
cur=con.cursor()

#User Inputs:
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
level1 = 'SQL Column Name 1'
level2 = 'SQL Column Name 2'

#Make Data Readable for SQL Query:
data = []
for i in df:
    info = df[i]
    data.append(info)

#Make SQL Query:
sql = """select count(IDS) from MY_TABLE 
where {col1} in {val1} 
or {col2} in    
{val2}""".format(col1=level1,val1=item,col2=level2,val2=item)

for item in data:
    row = cur.execute(sql).fetchall()
    counts.append(row)
print(counts)
```

I would like for this to run over every column in my CSV file (in this case, there are 8) and return a list of 8 counts that were pulled.  This is the error I'm getting:

\'1232671\']\'\nerror
("1232671" is the value of the last row in my first column)

^ found "\'" (at char 95) expecting `\'(\'\' (27) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Any help would be much appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: I don't see how your code can even run since you are assigning the value to `sql` before the loop in which `item` is defined so I would expect it to throw "NameError: name 'item' is not defined". Even if it doesn't throw an error I would expect the value of `sql` to be the same for each iteration of the loop. You could verify that by simply doing `print(sql)` immediately before `row = cur.execute(sql).fetchall()`.

Comment: Note also that an IN clause with discrete values expects a list of values in parentheses, even if that list only contains one element, e.g., `... WHERE columnname IN (123)` not `... WHERE columnname IN 123`

Comment: @GordThompson - That was my mistake. I try to re-define my variables when I posts questions to make it as clear as possible and I didn't update one of them.  my for loop under #Make Data Readable for SQL Query should be 'item' instead of 'info'.

Comment: @GordThompson - Thanks for the print(sql) tip!  This makes it so easy to identify the error.  You're absolutely right - my error is because right after my IN statement, the array is feeding in the row number (which I don't want included) followed by the IDs and there's no formatting (parenthesis, single quotes and comma separators).  If it's not too much to ask, would you know a way to get python to format a file to make it SQL readable?  Thanks for all your advice!

Comment: re: "a way to get python to format a file to make it SQL readable" - Not sure precisely what you mean. Connecting to a CSV or Excel file so you can pull values from it using SQL statements? The Access Database Engine has ODBC drivers for that. Do a bit of searching and ask a new question of you require further assistance.

Comment: @GordThompson - By SQL ready, I mean to have all each element in single quotes and comma separated (excluding the last value) just as they would be if I were working directly in SQL.  I'll check out the Access Database Engine you recommend and see what I can find.  Thanks so much for all of your input!